# How to express 72.27pt in terms of \oddsidemargin, \textwidth, ... that are subtracted from \paperwidth?

Tags: margins, paper-size

By default, LaTeX appends one inch (72.27pt) to the left (and top) of document.
Here I want to prove it as follows. But I missed some other page  layout macros to subtract from `\paperwidth`.

```
% the objective is to prove that
% left padding of 1in  = 72.27pt
% has been added by default
% by LaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \the
    \dimexpr
        \paperwidth
        -\hoffset
        -\oddsidemargin
        -\textwidth
        -\marginparsep
        -\marginparwidth
        % minus some other page layout macros 
        % should be there but I don't know
    \relax
\end{document}
```

How to express `72.27pt` in terms of `\oddsidemargin`, `\textwidth`, ... that are subtracted from `\paperwidth`?

---

I need a length macro for the red segment below.

[image]

---

The reason I accepted egreg answer is due to his comment below.

> Again: the length you display in red is not available directly, but
>   only through computation: it's
>   `\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth`

Thus it is impossible to get the required expression to prove `72.27pt`.

Comment: Load the **layout** package and say `\layout` as the only token in the document.

Comment: That length is not stored anywhere.

Comment: Again: the length you display in red is *not* available directly, but only through computation: it's `\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth`

Comment: \marginparpush is the minimum *vertical* separation between margin notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper left corner of the text block is placed

```
1in + \hoffset + \oddsidemargin
```

from the left border of the page and

```
1in + \voffset + \topmargin + \headheight + \headsep
```

from the upper border. Of course `\evensidemargin` is used when the page is considered to be a right page (only in `twosided` printing and when the page number is even).

You can "prove" what you want with the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{layout}

\addtolength{\marginparwidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth-1pt\relax}

\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

Now the box representing the margin note area will extend just a bit short of the right edge of the paper (1pt, actually, but the image is not perfect because the lines have a thickness).

The length you draw in red is exactly

```
\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth
```

If all you need is a nonstandard page size with zero margins, the answer is **geometry**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=1in,paperheight=1in,margin=0pt]{geometry}
```

The calculations performed by the package are summarized in the `log` file:

```
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(0.0pt, 72.26999pt, 0.0pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(0.0pt, 72.26999pt, 0.0pt)
* \paperwidth=72.26999pt
* \paperheight=72.26999pt
* \textwidth=72.26999pt
* \textheight=72.26999pt
* \oddsidemargin=-72.26999pt
* \evensidemargin=-72.26999pt
* \topmargin=-109.26999pt
```

Note that 72.27pt is the same as 72.26999pt, as far as TeX is concerned.

Comment: how to prove `1in` has been added to the document? Please express it in terms of the available page length macros. It was the objective of my code snippet above.

Comment: it is totally nonsense to use `\hoffset` for that. It is meant to correct problems with a printer and not for setting paper margins. Enrico already told you how this can be done.

Comment: No, `\hoffset`is never needed!

Comment: see answer for left and top margin. The `\layout` tells you what to do if right and bottom margin should also be 0pt